Water at zero degrees Celsius: proportions of liquid vs ice?
Suppose I put water on a dish, and I put it in contact with a heat bath whose temperature is zero degrees Celsius. I have two questions:

Given enough time, will the proportions of liquid water vs ice converge to some fixed ratio?

Will the water "forget" its initial condition, given enough time? I.e., independently of whether the initial state is completely solid or completely liquid (or some mixture of both), will the long-future state be the same?



Beyond cooling to zero, how much enthalpy are you pulling out?

Textbooks tell you directly that you can have any proportion you like. It is indeterminate right at the melting point. You have to specify exactly how much latent heat you are leaving in the system.

@naturallyInconsistent are you saying that we will have convergence to fixed proportions and the ratio will be a function of the initial amount of latent heat?

Are you ignoring evaporation, and humidity in the ambient atmosphere?

There is no such thing as "initial amount of latent heat". Rather, you get to melting point, and then you get to pull or push on the piston, changing the volume at constant pressure and temperature, and get arbitrary amounts of ice v.s. water. That pulling or pushing really just ends up pulling or pushing heat from the heat bath, and corresponds to the latent heat when inside the ice-water system. If you are not fixing the volume, and instead let the pressure vary, it gets difficult to interpret.

The term “heat bath” normally refers to a constant temperature environment, i.e., an environment whose temperature doesn’t change during heat transfer. Is this what you mean?

@naturallyInconsistent The only constraints are that temperature is zero degrees Celsius and constant (because of the heat bath), and pressure is atmospheric and constant (suppose the heat bath is just air). There is no volume constraint. We have just water on a dish. Given these conditions, I am looking for answers to the two questions I posed.

@BobD yes, that's what I mean.

@PM2Ring to keep it simple, I ignore these factors.

@Plemath is the water temperature greater than 0C before placing it in the heat bath?

@BobD  No, it is exactly 0C.

@Plemath is it pure water at 0C before putting it in the bath?

@BobD Yes it is.

@naturallyInconsistent What piston are you talking about? The OP doesn't mention any form of piston!

@PM2Ring The OP didn't specify enough to know if it is fixed volume or fixed pressure. Now that it is clarified that it is fixed pressure, we can give a more complete answer. As mentioned above, when the system is to be analysed at fixed pressure, things will become very much more complicated. The usual, and intuitive, behaviour that we are familiar with, clearly shows a step function phase change; at the fixed (atmospheric) pressure and at the melting/boiling point, the whole system transitions abruptly. That is what happens in the thermodynamic limit.

But actual finite systems are not in the thermodynamic limit. This means that the system will then have a smooth but very steep curve that approximates the Heaviside step function, and the system will exhibit extreme sensitivity to the conditions, both the pressure and the temperature of the heat bath. The proportion of melted v.s. frozen would be fixed by this extreme sensitivity, but there will be almost no predictibility because nobody can control their heat bath pressure and temperature to a level of precision to fix this. This hasnt even included the fact that fluctuations dominate.

@naturallyInconsistent  Is there a reference (textbook/paper) that describes the behaviour you are claiming?

It shouldn't be in Pippard, but it might be an exercise or something in Callen or Kittel & Kroemer, or another book. It is quite horrible, and I don't want to revisit the trauma.



Given enough time, will the proportions of liquid water vs ice converge to some fixed ratio?


You have stated in comments that the water is at 0$^0$C prior to placing it in the 0$^0$C heat bath. If that’s the case then whatever the proportion of liquid water vs ice is before placing in the bath will remain the same after placing it in the bath no matter how long it is there. In order for (additional) ice to form latent heat needs to be extracted. That requires the bath to be at a lower temperature than the mixture. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Without a temperature difference there can be no heat. This applies to latent heat as well as sensible heat (heat that results in temperature changes).


Will the water "forget" its initial condition, given enough time? I.e., independently of whether the initial state is completely solid
or completely liquid (or some mixture of both), will the long-future
state be the same?


For the reason stated above the water’s initial condition will remain unchanged unless heat is extracted, and that can’t happen unless the bath temperature is below 0$^0$C. Then the final proportion of ice to liquid water will depend on how long it remains in the lower temperature bath, eventually becoming all ice when reaching thermal equilibrium with the bath.
Hope this helps.
